# let or struct vs enum

Tags: swift, struct, enums

```
enum category: UInt32 {
    case fence = 1
    case paddle = 2
    case block = 4
    case ball = 8
}

struct category{
    static var fence:UInt32 = 1
    static var paddle:UInt32 = 2
    static var block:UInt32 = 4
    static var category:UInt32 = 8
}
```

trying to create a set of bitMasks, I am wondering which one is the proper way to do this.

enum or struct ?

Comment: None of the above. Use an OptionSet. (Okay, that's a struct, but you need to construct it differently for it to be an OptionSet.)

Comment: your right! thanks for the answer

Comment: No problem. It's more work to construct an Option Set but once you've done it, it's a wonderful thing to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is an Option Set. That is Swift's way of letting you build a bitmask, such that you can then manipulate it like a set, which is really nice.

There's a fine example in the Swift docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/index.html

Newer version here:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optionset